# EF: Dependency injection in entities

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EntityFramework and my entity has some dependencies. The question is: how can I inject dependencies in Entity Framework?

Comment: Entity Framework expects entities to have a parameterless constructor, which fits with the fact they are POCOs. I'm not sure I understand why you would want to inject something into a poco object, ideally it should just be a representation of the state of a row in a database.

Comment: Are the dependencies other entities? If so, would eager loading help?